# How to update npm on a remote server?

Tags: npm

I'm trying to update npm to a specific version on a remote server that already has node (v0.10.48) and npm (v1.3.6) installed but their versions are too old.

When I run the command:

```
npm install npm@5.6.0
```

the updated is done correctly, but when I run

```
npm -v
```

to check the version is still the old one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try the `-g` flag

Comment: I'm getting "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator." when I use -g flag

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

```
sudo npm install npm@5.6.0
```